# Python: AttributeError: module 'core' has no attribute 'children'

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, attributeerror, kivymd

Hello I'm working on mobile application with kivy and python.
Everything was fine until I wanted to use sqlite3.
Here is my directory structure:

```
application
├───main.py
├───core
│   └───__pycache__
|   ├───calendar_screen.py
|   ├───children.py
|   ├───menu.py
|   ├───screen_manager.py
|   ├───settings.py
|   └───vaccination.py
├───database
|   ├───vaccination_calendar.db
|   ├───vaccination_calendar.py
│   └───__pycache__
├───fonts
│   └───static
│       ├───OpenSans
│       ├───OpenSans_Condensed
│       └───OpenSans_SemiCondensed
├───images
│   └───icons
├───layouts
|   ├───calendar.kv
|   ├───children.kv
|   ├───menu.kv
|   ├───screen_manager.kv
|   ├───settings.kv
|   └───vaccination.kv
└───__pycache__
```

Relevent code
main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp

from core.screen_manager import WindowManager


class VaccinationCalendarApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        return WindowManager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    VaccinationCalendarApp().run()
```

screen_manager.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

Builder.load_file("layouts/screen_manager.kv")


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
```

screen_manager.kv

```
#: import Menu core.menu
#: import Calendar core.calendar_screen
#: import Children core.children
#: import Vaccination core.vaccination
#: import Settings core.settings

<WindowManager>:
    Menu:
    Calendar:
    Children:
    Vaccination:
    SettingsScreen:
```

children.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineAvatarIconListItem, IconLeftWidget
from application.database.vaccination_calendar import get_children

Builder.load_file("layouts/children.kv")

class Children(Screen):
    pass
```

vaccination_calendar.py

```
import sqlite3

def get_children():
    statement = "select * from children"

    with sqlite3.connect("vaccination_calendar.db") as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(statement)
        children_list = [{"id": child[0], "name": child[1], "birth_date": child[2], "days_age": child[3]}
                         for child in cursor.fetchall()]
        conn.commit()

    return children_list
```

Everything was fine until this line in children.py:
from application.database.vaccination_calendar import get_children.
After adding this line I get AttributeError with traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\przem\PycharmProjects\vaccination_calendar\application\main.py", line 3, in <module>
   File "C:\Users\przem\PycharmProjects\vaccination_calendar\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 305, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\przem\PycharmProjects\vaccination_calendar\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 372, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "C:\Users\przem\PycharmProjects\vaccination_calendar\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 483, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "C:\Users\przem\PycharmProjects\vaccination_calendar\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 590, in parse
     self.execute_directives()
   File "C:\Users\przem\PycharmProjects\vaccination_calendar\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 559, in execute_directives
     mod = getattr(mod, part)
 AttributeError: module 'core' has no attribute 'children'
```

I suspect that it is something wrong with circular dependency but tbh i can't see anything wrong with this.
File i past here are in imported order starting from main.py
Any idea what is wrong?

I tried to import vaccination_calendar.py by method in children.py but after that i get ModuleNotFoundError I also tried to import in to main.py and there it works but then i don't see any idea to use vaccination_calendar.py in children screen.

Comment: Why did you wrap code  in single and triple backticks? I ask because I'm seeing this often, starting recently, and want to understand why it's happening. The markdown guide doesn't suggest this as the correct way to format code in questions.

Comment: @MichaelRuth First i tried to add question only in triple backticks but it didn't let me add question showing an error to use ctrl + K on lines of code so i added only single and it didn't work too. It worked with single and triple :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error can be found in the following line:

```py
from application.database.vaccination_calendar import get_children
```

I assume you run `main.py`. When you do so `./application` gets added to `sys.path`. That is why Python will never be able to resolve a module path like `application.some.module_path`, instead it should only be the `some.module_path` part.

The error message is pretty cryptic, but that is the result of Kivy trying to parse the `screen_manager.kv` file. In the process of doing so it finds this wrong import and raises an error deep inside the Kivy library (cause it tries to parse a `.kv` file) instead of directly telling you what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution to this problem.
I don't know where exactly was the problem but I change the way I import vaccination_calendar.
I change this:

```
from application.database.vaccination_calendar import get_children
```

To this:

```
sys.path.append('database')

import vaccination_calendar
```

Pycharm still see a problem but it works for me.
Maybe someone can use it.